# Where does iTunes save iOS updates?

Tags: itunes, ios, disk-space

When I choose to install a new version of iOS on my device via iTunes, the installation file is huge (e.g. 750 MB). Where does iTunes save this file, and does it get deleted after the installation is done?

Comment: I was told elsewhere (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371215/how-to-fix-itunes-downloading-ios-update-but-not-installing) that someone's update was four gigabytes (not 750 MB).  Mine was 3585 MB and took over an hour to download.

Comment: On Win10 the location for me was C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\AppleInc.iTunes_nzyj5cx40ttqa\LocalCache\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**On Windows XP**
`Documents and Settings\<User>\Application Data\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates`

**On Windows Vista/Windows 7**
`Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates`

**Windows 8/10**
`\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes\`

**Windows 10 (latest)**
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\AppleInc.iTunes_nzyj5cx40ttqa\LocalCache\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates`

**On Mac**
`~/Library/iTunes/iPhone Software Updates`

I believe that the updates do not delete after they are installed.

Via [this iPhone FAQ article](http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/97320).

Comment: I have only 5.1 there, so I am guessing the previous ones are deleted when a new one is downloaded.

Comment: Where is it stored in windows 8?

Comment: and for iPad the path is ~/Library/iTunes/iPad Software Updates/

Comment: Is it safe to remove these (update) installation files? I just upgraded my iPad and iPod to iOS 8 and am running very low on disk space on my Mac.

Comment: Yes, these are only where your Mac stores the files used to update your device.

Answer (score 5):

On Mac, you can delete the iOS firmware by going to Finder, pressing <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and go to `~/Library/iTunes/iPhone Software Updates`. From there, you can delete the files.

You don't have to delete them unless you are short on disk space, as they get replaced by newly downloaded files whenever there is an upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

C:\ProgramData\Apple Computer\iTunes